# Rails 3: session gets cleared between requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session

I'm running into a really weird problem, which is very inconsistent. I have a one-page application, that requests json from my Rails 3 app every so many seconds. On the server side, I store the browser's session information, using `active_record_store`.

The problem is that between two requests, sometimes the session info gets cleared. Here's a piece of the log:

```
Started GET "/channels/2/show_next_slide.json?current_slide_slot_id=1806" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 11:35:10 +0200
Processing by ChannelsController#show_next_slide as 
  Parameters: {"current_slide_slot_id"=>"1806", "id"=>"2"}
******* Test=
******* Session ID=ff7010bb1db040b90caa965b7736ad25
...
******* Test=1806
******* Session ID=ff7010bb1db040b90caa965b7736ad25
Completed 200 OK in 148ms (Views: 3.3ms | ActiveRecord: 4.3ms)
127.0.0.1 GET /channels/2/show_next_slide.json?current_slide_slot_id=1806 200 OK ChannelsController#show_next_slide JSON 148.1 (DB 4.3, View 3.3) {"current_slide_slot_id"=>"1806", "id"=>"2"} {}


Started GET "/assets/plugins/w/101d.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 11:35:14 +0200
Served asset /plugins/w/101d.png - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/plugins/w/102n.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 11:35:14 +0200
Served asset /plugins/w/102n.png - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/plugins/w/103n.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 11:35:14 +0200
Served asset /plugins/w/103n.png - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/plugins/w/109.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 11:35:14 +0200
Served asset /plugins/w/109.png - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/channels/2/show_next_slide.json?current_slide_slot_id=1806" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 11:35:15 +0200
Processing by ChannelsController#show_next_slide as 
Parameters: {"current_slide_slot_id"=>"1806", "id"=>"2"}
******* Test=
******* Session ID=ff7010bb1db040b90caa965b7736ad25
```

In the `application_controller` I've setup a before_filter and after_filter to write the contents of `session[:test]` to the log (shown as `******* Test=`). As you can see: the first request ends with `session[:test]=1806` but then upon the next request `session[:test]` is empty. This happens occasionally; not always.

As you can see, the session ID is the same in both requests. Also, the `csrf` token is passed along just fine. Just to be sure I disabled `protect_from_forgery`, but that does not make any difference. So that does not seem to be a problem.

The only other "third party code" that I use and that does something with the session is Devise. So maybe there is something happening there, but I can't think of anything...

Does anyone have a clue as to what might be going on here?

## Additional info

In the application_controller, I call the following method in both the before_filter and after_filter:

```
def log_session_for_debugging
  logger.debug("******* Test=#{session[:test]}")
  logger.debug("******* Session ID=#{request.session_options[:id]}")
end
```

I assign a value to `session[:test]` right before the render command in the show_next_slide controller action:

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { 
      session[:test] = @slide_slot.to_param
      render :json => @slide_slot ? @slide_slot.as_json_with_slide_and_elements() : {} 
    }
  end
```

Comment: devise does crazy stuff with the session, but it usually creates a new session, it does not fuzz with contents of a session. i think you should monitor the request headers that are contained in the rails response. this might indicate a problem. the client should always recieve the session data on each request.

Comment: Could you show the before and after filter as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found the exact cause of the problem, but I did have a bit of code that allowed users with a certain role to log in in an alternate way. i was using Warden-level code for that. I have switched to using an additional Devise strategy (following this [this great article](http://kyan.com/blog/2013/10/11/devise-authentication-strategies)) and that made the problem go away.